# Examples of changing a project's focus as a result of design

Tags: case-studies

I'm giving a short talk on interaction design practices, and one of the topics I'm covering is how a product's concept can change during design. That is, you start a project intending to solve problem A. But as you work on the design, you realize that problem A is the wrong problem to solve. So you change focus and work on problem B instead.

In my talk, I'd like to give examples of this shift. Preferably with examples from reasonably well-known products or companies. (I have examples from my own work, but I think high-profile examples will be more persuasive.) **What are some good examples of changing a product's focus, as a result of design work?**

Many startups have made this kind of shift after launching a product. (E.g., [Groupon started out as an advocacy platform](http://www.fastcompany.com/1778706/eric-ries-lean-startup-machine), before pivoting to consumer discounts.) That's not quite what I'm looking for. I want to show how good design can lead to a pivot, before launching a product.

Comment: The Lean Startup from Eric Ries (http://www.amazon.com/Lean-Startup-Entrepreneurs-Continuous-Innovation/dp/0307887898/) comes to mind. I think there are a few examples in there, but I can't remember if they are pivots because of design choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [talk by Adrian Westaway at IXDA 12](http://www.ixda.org/resources/adrian-westaway-bananas-technology-and-magic) might be close to what you are looking for. The design company was asked to design a phone for seniors, but they ended up redesigning the out-of-box experience instead.